# R Shiny: Use Onclick Option of Actionbutton on the Server Side

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I want to make a Shiny App in which the user can press an actionbutton which would then trigger some code on the server side creating a file in the www folder and then opens/downloads the file.

Suppose the file is test.txt (in my case it would be a variety of R, Excel, and exe files which will be copied from different folders on a drive to the www folder).

My first try was to use the actionbutton with the onclick option as shown below

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
      actionButton("showtxt", "Show/Download File", onclick = "window.open('test.txt')")
    )


    server <- function(input, output, session){
      observeEvent(input$showtxt,{
        # Write some text
        write.table(c("Test"), file = "www/test.txt")
      })
    }


    shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

But this doesn't work since the onclick action is done before the observevent is evaluated.

I then tried to call a function inside to the onclick option as shown below

```
    CreateFileAndLink <- function(){
      write.table(c("Test"), file = "www/test.txt")
      return("window.open('test.txt')")
    }

    ui <- fluidPage(
      actionButton("showtxt", "Show/Download File", onclick = CreateFileAndLink())
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session){}

    shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

This works but has the downside that now the file is created when upon opening the Shiny App as opposed to creating the file when the user clicks the actionbutton. This is very inefficient if I were to use this piece of code multiple times in an App with relatively large files.

Maybe it is possible to make sure that the observevent is executed before the onclick-action, or maybe use the onclick option on the server side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

**UPDATE:**

I found out that the great *shinyjs* package by Dean Attali contains a onclick function that might be of help here. I tried to run the code below but it didn't work :/

```
    library(shinyjs)
    ui <- fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),
      actionButton("showtxt", "Show/Download File")
    )


    server <- function(input, output, session){
      observeEvent(input$showtxt,{
        # Write some text
        write.table(c("Test"), file = "www/test.txt")

        # Call Onclick
        onclick("showtxt", "window.open('test.txt')")
      })
    }


    shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Are you asking about `downloadButton`? [link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadButton.html)

Comment: I see how that could work, but I like the way the browser tries to open the file (if it for example is a .txt or .pdf file).  I found a solution using the onclick function which is will post below as an answer (when StackOverflow let me do it). But thanks for your comment. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution using the onclick function from the **shinyjs** package.

```
    library(shinyjs)
    ui <- fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),
      actionButton("showtxt", "Show/Download File")
    )


    server <- function(input, output, session){
      observeEvent(input$showtxt,{
        # Write some text
        write.table(c("Test"), file = "www/test.txt")
      })


      # Call Onclick
      onclick("showtxt", runjs("window.open('test.txt')"))
    }


    shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```